# validation to disallow a single character (<) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to disallow the < character in first_name in our model. What would the regex for this be?

I tried

```
  validates :first_name, format: { with: /[^<]/ }
```

but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Slightly more correct is `\A` instead of `^` - `\A` is for start of string rather than start of line (even though they should be the same here). https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors

Comment: @DaveSlutzkin the `^` in this case has nothing to do with start of line it is an exclusionary character class e.g. any character except `<`

Comment: While one could answer this question as `with: /\A((?!<).)*\z/` [This SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) offers a much better explanation than I would have

Comment: @engineersmnky Oh yeah! I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `without` instead of `with` in the validation
You may want to escape the less-than, as [zishe suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54258791/385532), but I don't think this is necessary.

```
validates :first_name, format: { without: /</ }
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#format

edit: incorporated @engineersmnky points, much simpler.

Comment: The "hat" inside a character class means any character **Not** in this class. However the OP's validation will only fail if the **Only** character is `"<"`

Answer (score 0):

You are currently only capturing the first character. So you probably want to do something like `[^<].*` (a string starting with anything but `<` and followed by arbitrary characters)